# JAXB to class with Variables as in element name

Tags: jaxb, xjc

The element name starts with caps. When I try to generate classes with help of JAXB or XJC command, It follows default Java Naming convention - camel case for variable names.

Bellow is the XSD

`<xs:element name="Meta" type="tns:FieldArray" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>`

Bellow is the auto generated POJO

```
@XmlElement(name = "Meta")
protected FieldArray meta;
```

I'm expecting FiledArray object to be named as Meta as in XSD instead of meta as per Java naming conventions.

I've came across an option to force JAXB to disable enableJavaNamingConventions with below binding.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bindings version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <globalBindings  enableJavaNamingConventions="false">
        </globalBindings>
    </bindings>
```

But it's not working with both xjc command and JAXB classes from schema of eclipse.

Comment: "... as per Java naming conventions." - According to common Java naming conventions, variables start with a lower-case letter, so you should expect `meta` and not `Meta`.

Comment: The same POJO is used for both SOAP and Rest based communication. The Server expects JSON key as Meta not meta . I don't want to use GSON serializedname annotation. Because I've about 60 classes, each has 10+  Variables. Thus if I can generate JAXB classes with object name as Meta, My JSON key won't have any discrepancies.